# execute sql loader as administrator from java app

Tags: java, sql, windows, cmd

My requirement is to load a script using sql loader from within my java app. For this purpose, I've been using the following script

```
D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN\SQLLDR.EXE userid=myDBUserID/myDBPswrd  data=C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\sql_ldr_files\1\table_export_DATA.ldr control=C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\sql_ldr_files\1\table_export_DATA.ctl log=C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\sql_ldr_files\1\logitit.log discard=C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\sql_ldr_files\1\discard.txt bad=C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\sql_ldr_files\1\bad.txt
```

But while trying to run it first on cmd prompt, i realized that the command won't run if I do not run it, on cmd prompt which is launched by "Run as Administrator".

Once the cmd was launched by "Run as Administrator", the command ran successfully, the script executed and the table got populated properly.

Now my task was to use the same code, but run it from within a java code. For this, I've used the following java code,

```
  import java.io.FileWriter.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader.*;
import java.io.InputStreamReader.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RunSqlLrdFromJava
{   
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
    try{
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String sqlLoaderPath = "D:\\oracle\\product\\10.2.0\\db_1\\BIN\\";
        String runAsCmd="runas /user:myPCName\\administrator ";
    String cmd = runAsCmd + "\""+sqlLoaderPath + "SQLLDR.EXE userid=myDBUserID/myDBPswrd "
                            + " data=C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\sql_ldr_files\\1\\table_export_DATA.ldr"
                            + " control=C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\sql_ldr_files\\1\\table_export_DATA.ctl"
                            + " log=C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\sql_ldr_files\\1\\logitit.log"
                            + " discard=C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\sql_ldr_files\\1\\discard.txt"
                        + " bad=C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\sql_ldr_files\\1\\bad.txt " + "\"";
        try{                    

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("ExceptionInSqlldr.txt");
        BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(file);
        bf.write("SQLLDR COMMAND:\n" +cmd +"---------------------------------\n\n\n");
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
        String line;
        System.out.println("\n------------------exitVal:"+exitVal+"------------------\n\n");
        bf.write("SQLLDR COMMAND:\n" +cmd +"---------------------------------\n\n\n");
        if(br!=null && exitVal!=0)
        {   while((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                bf.write("\n"+ line +"\n");
                System.out.println("Read from error stream: \"" + line + "\"");
            }
        }


        proc.destroy();

        bf.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        }       

    }
```

But this time, it won't run.

My problem is, when we use "run as" to run the process as administrator on command prompt, it prompts for a password. Thus when  I'm using the same "run as" command from within a java code, I can't provide the response to that prompt [as it seems at the least].

Is there a wayout, where I can run the command as an administrator from within my java code by passing the password for administrator inside the command only, so that my java code becomes successfull in running it?

Please advice as I didn't ever do it before.

Warm regards.

Comment: You shouldn't be needing (nor using) an Administrator account. What is the error you get when you don't. My guess is wrong privileges on the *input* file. You should fix that, rather than working around the real problem.

Comment: "SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIEnvCreate [-1]"

I get this error as I'm running the java code from cmd prompt launched from my normal user account. Now when I'm launching the cmd prompt by using "Run as administrator", I'm getting no error at all and the script loads successfully.

Comment: U see, This is what my problem is. When I'll be using this code from within my app, it might just not have the "administrator" as its user. By then, I'll face the same error. :(

Can we not run the command as administrator  by using the "run as" syntax, with the password passed as a param to it?

Comment: You should find the real reason why you get that error. Sounds like the Oracle client is not installed properly (or only accessible to the administrator). Running that as administrator is not a fix it's an ugly workaround. And no, there is no way to use runas without the password prompt.

Comment: Well u're correct. The real problem was my desktop was having UAC(User Access Ctrl) level set to medium. Thats y any application when tried to be invoked explicitly asked for Admin privilege. Now that I have turned that thing off, the java code is working absolutely fine. Thanks for the help.